# Cohomology ring with $\mathbb{Z}_n$ coefficient

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

There are many results of cohomology ring with integer or $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients. Can one from those knowledge to obtain cohomology ring with $\mathbb{Z}_n$ coefficient, $H^*(M^d, \mathbb{Z}_n)$, in the spirit of universal coefficient theorem (with possible input from $H_*(M^d, \mathbb{Z}_n)$).

For example, we know both $H^*(\mathbb{RP}^3, \mathbb{Z})$ and $H^*(\mathbb{RP}^3, \mathbb{Z}_2)$. But what is $H^*(\mathbb{RP}^3, \mathbb{Z}_n)$?

Comment: I don't know of a "universal coefficient theorem" that only takes in the inputs you've specified - the usual theorem also requires knowing $H_*(M, \mathbb{Z})$. But in principle you can change coefficients quite easily on the level of cochains.  This is the approach I would use in the case $M = \mathbb{R}P^3$, and in any case the answer can be found [here](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Cohomology_of_real_projective_space) for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link does not contain cohomology ring with $\mathbb{Z}_n$ coefficient (only $\mathbb{Z}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cohomology groups are finitely generated, then you can fiddle to recover the homology and then the cohomology *groups* with arbitrary coefficients from $H^*(X; \Bbb Z)$ through the universal coefficient theorem. But the ring structure does not respect the universal coefficient theorem. Best to take whatever way you computed the cohomology ring originally and then do it with different coefficients.

As an explicit example, $L(3,1)$ and $M_3 \vee S^3$ have the same $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/2$ cohomology rings (the cup product is stupid in both), but different $\Bbb Z/3$ cohomology rings. (Here $M_3$ is $S^1 \cup_f D^2$, where $f: S^1 \to S^1$ is given by $z \mapsto z^3$.) $H^*(L(3,1);\Bbb Z/3)$ is generated by an $\alpha$ in degree $1$, a $\beta$ in degree 2, and satisfies that $\alpha \beta$ is the generator in degree 3; at the same time $H^*(M_3 \vee S^3)$ certainly doesn't have a degree 1 and 2 generator that have a nonzero product in degree 3.

Comment: I wonder if we know cohomology ring with $\mathbb{Z}_p$ coefficients and  $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficient, where $p$ is a prime so that .$\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field, in this case can we derive the cohomology ring with $\mathbb{Z}_n$ coefficient for other integer $n$.

Comment: No. Try $\Bbb{RP}^3 \# L(3,1)$ vs $L(6,1)$. A generator in $\Bbb Z/6$ first cohomology squares to a generator in second cohomology in the first example, but it squares to twice that in the second.

Comment: I wonder if someone already calculated the ring $H^*(\mathbb{RP}^3, \mathbb{Z}_n)$?